# Проблема с overlay меню: не могу отключить при переходе по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема с *overlay* меню: не могу отключить при переходе по ссылке

```js
$(function() {
  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
     $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

.menu-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-overlay {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.menu-overlay a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 2%;
  margin:  25% 1% 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu hidden-lg">
   <span class="menu-circle"></span>
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      <span class="menu-icon">
         <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
         <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
         <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
      </span>
   </a>
</div> 
<div class="menu-overlay">
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Service</a>
   <a href="#">Work</a>
   <a href="#">Blog</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENqRpV

Comment: А можете отформатировать и сделать ваш код запускаемым? Это выглядит нечитаемо. Если возможно, также сократите код до проблемного места.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, готово )

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить такой же обработчик на click элемента меню. Если в коде ничего другого не происходит, то `preventDefault` не нужен.

```
$(".menu-link, .menu-overlay > a").click(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```